# 'line of sight' from numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, line

I'm using a numpy array of 0s and 1s to represent collision in a game map, co-ords set as 1 represent a wall.

What I need to do is a line of sight test from point A to B. So, given the values `startX`, `startY`, `endX` and `endY`, I need to get all values from my numpy array in a straight line, and if any of those are a wall (1) then there is no line of sight.

Is there a way to get a line of values from numpy? Or is this probably the wrong way to go about it?

Any pointers?

Comment: Hi, what you need is Bresenham's algorithm, perhaps modified. Here's some information: http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Bresenham%27s_Line_Algorithm

Comment: What if the line of sight isn't a perfect vertical/horizontal/diagonal line? How should indices that are partially in the line of sight? And how do you define partially in that case? Does each element represent a square/circle or a more complicated polygon?

Comment: Thank you for the link, looks just what I need. There should be no partials as everything in my game is grid based (movement, obstacles etc)... I'm guessin?

Answer (score 2):

As said [Daniel F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4427777/daniel-f), this can be an implementation. I improved, completed and fixed its implementation.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones([7, 7])
a[3, 3] = 1
a[1, :] = 2
a[4, :] = 2

b = 1 - a
b = b.astype(bool)

startX = 3
startY = 0
endX = 3
endY = 5
n = 4  # Steps per unit distance
dxy = (np.sqrt((endX - startX) ** 2 + (endY - startY) ** 2)) * n
i = np.rint(np.linspace(startX, endX, dxy)).astype(int)
j = np.rint(np.linspace(startY, endY, dxy)).astype(int)
has_collision = np.any(b[i, j])

print("Has collision", has_collision)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple implementation

```
coll = np.random.randint(0, 2, (100,100)) # collision matrix
n = 4 # bigger for more accurate, less speed
dxy = (startX - endX + startY - endY) * n
i = np.rint(np.linspace(startX, endX, dxy))
j = np.rint(np.linspace(startY, endY, dxy))
collision = np.any(coll[i, j])
```